# Automatically check Powerpoint reference if available?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Is there a way to automatically have Excel 2010 "check off" the Powerpoint reference in the VBA references automatically before running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.  Let me know if it gives you any trouble (I modified some of my existing functions and I might have a typo/etc.

Note: this is for Office 2010.

```
Const PPTReference as String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\POWERPOINT.EXE"
Const PPTDescription as String = "Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object Library"

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call AddRefToPowerPointObjectLibrary
End Sub

Private Sub AddRefToPowerPointObjectLibrary()
'Adds a programmatic refernce to Excel, if one does not already exist

    If Not RefExists(PPTReference, PPTDescription) Then
        Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile PPTReference

    Else:
        'Already Installed

    End If

End Sub

Function RefExists(refPath As String, refDescrip As String) As Boolean
'Returns true/false if a specified reference exists, based on LIKE comparison
' to reference.description.
Dim ref As Variant
Dim bExists As Boolean

'Assume the reference doesn't exist
bExists = False

For Each ref In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References
    If ref.Description Like refDescrip Then
        PPT_RefExists = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
PPT_RefExists = bExists
End Function
```

**Update:**

This code *must be run* before you call any procedure that relies one early-binding to the PowerPoint object model.

For example, you **cannot do this**:

```
Sub DontDoThis()
    Dim pptApp as PowerPoint.Application

    AddRefToPowerPointObjectLibrary

    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    'more code...

End Sub
```

It might be most reliable to put the above code in the Workbook_Open event handler, revised above.

Comment: Hmmm for some reason my other module is still throwing off errors because I have stuff like "Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application" written. It won't let me call your code before calling the other module (i.e. for some reason it's getting held up over the object declaration before running the reference adder)

Comment: You would have to call this code *before* you call **ANY** procedure that relies on early-binding to the PowerPoint.Application object.  You could try putting it in the `Workbook_Open` event handler.

Comment: I wonder if changing everything to late binding would be better? Workbook_Open sounds like a good idea as well

Comment: If you change to late-binding, then you don't need the reference (and having it will NOT enable intellisense).  I would put it in the Workbook_Open event.